# How to normalize JSON data in scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, normalization

I want to convert this json to a normalized table structure in scala/spark

not sure how to proceed to get this structure.

```
{
    "codeDescData": {
        "codeCategory": "alphabets",
        "fieldName": "alpha fieldname",
        "codes": [{
            "code": "XYZ",
            "codeDescription": "LAST 3 OF 26"
        },
        {
            "code": "KLM",
            "codeDescription": "Somewhere in the middle",

        }],
        "otherCodes:[{
            "key":"ABC",
            "KeyDescription":"descriptionofABC"
        },
        {
            "key":"DEF",
            "keyDescription":"DescriptionforDEF"
        }
        ]"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What does the code you have look like?

Comment: can you share your expected o/p

Comment: What is your problem, to create parse the Json into a Dataset or Dataframe, or is your problem to automatically generate a normalized model?

Comment: I understand parsing the json but how do can i automatically step through the structures and find the cartesian product of the data